# Create multiple functions to return separate dictionary results in 1 result box?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have spent some time updating my code. I am trying to create a tool which returns acronyms. I have created separate dictionaries for each letter of the alphabet and have created a result box to return what the acronym stands for. However when running the code I can only get the latest dictionary to return a result i.e. any acronyms  in the 'c' dictionary, and each time I add a new dictionary I lose the function of the previous. I am quite new to coding and I have done a lot of research of previous questions before asking this, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks. This is the code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import*

acronym_dictionary={"A":"Annual", "AC":"Air Conditioning",
                    }

acronym_dictionary_b={"BA":"British Airway", "BB":"BumbleBee",
                      }                    

acronym_dictionary_c={"Ca":"Calcium","Co":"Company",
                      }

def Return_Entry(en):
    content= entry.get()
    result= acronym_dictionary.get(content, "Not found")
    print(result)
    resultBox.delete(0,END)
    resultBox.insert(0,result)

def Return_EntryB(en):
    content= entry.get()
    result= acronym_dictionary_b.get(content, "Not found")
    print(result)
    resultBox.delete(0,END)
    resultBox.insert(0,result)`

def Return_EntryC(en):
    content= entry.get()
    result= acronym_dictionary_c.get(content, "Not found")
    print(result)
    resultBox.delete(0,END)
    resultBox.insert(0,result)

def EntryDel():
    resultBox.delete(0,END)
    entry.delete(0,END)

master=Tk()
master.title("The Acronym Search Engine")
master.geometry('500x400')`



Button(master, text="Clear",command=EntryDel).grid(row=7, sticky=W)`

Label(master, text="A:").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
entry=Entry()
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry.bind('<Return>', Return_Entry)

Label(master, text="B:").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
entry=Entry()
entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry.bind('<Return>', Return_EntryB)`

Label(master, text="C:").grid(row=2, sticky=W)
entry=Entry()
entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry.bind('<Return>',Return_EntryC)

Label(master, text="Result:").grid( row=3,column=0 )
resultBox=Entry(master)
resultBox.grid(row=3,column=1)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you looking to have all 3 entry fields display some result in the results box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needed a bit of work. You were overwriting `entry` variable and so only the last box you created was able to be accessed. This had nothing to do with you removing `master` as you mentioned in the comments section. What you needed to do is give a unique name to each field. Then for each function you need to change the `content` to reflect the correct fields.

Here is your code reworked and also changed some function/variable names and spacing to reflect PEP8 standards.

```
import tkinter as tk

acronym_dictionary = {"A": "Annual", "AC": "Air Conditioning"}
acronym_dictionary_b = {"BA": "British Airway", "BB": "BumbleBee"}
acronym_dictionary_c = {"Ca": "Calcium", "Co": "Company"}


def return_entry(event):
    content = entry.get()
    result = acronym_dictionary.get(content, "Not found")
    print(result)
    result_box.delete(0, "end")
    result_box.insert("end", result)


def return_entry_b(event):
    content = entry2.get()
    result = acronym_dictionary_b.get(content, "Not found")
    print(result)
    result_box.delete(0, "end")
    result_box.insert("end", result)


def return_entry_c(event):
    content = entry3.get()
    result = acronym_dictionary_c.get(content, "Not found")
    print(result)
    result_box.delete(0, "end")
    result_box.insert("end", result)


def entry_del():
    result_box.delete(0, "end")
    entry.delete(0, "end")
    entry2.delete(0, "end")
    entry3.delete(0, "end")

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("The Acronym Search Engine")
master.geometry('200x110')

tk.Button(master, text="Clear", command=entry_del).grid(row=7, sticky="w")
tk.Label(master, text="A:", anchor="e").grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
tk.Label(master, text="B:", anchor="e").grid(row=1, sticky="ew")
tk.Label(master, text="C:", anchor="e").grid(row=2, sticky="ew")
tk.Label(master, text="Result:").grid(row=3, column=0)

entry = tk.Entry(master)
entry2 = tk.Entry(master)
entry3 = tk.Entry(master)
result_box = tk.Entry(master)
#result_box = tk.Text(master, width=40, height=3)

entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
result_box.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

entry.bind('<Return>', return_entry)
entry2.bind('<Return>', return_entry_b)
entry3.bind('<Return>', return_entry_c)

master.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

That said there is actually a better way to do this than creating a separate dictionary/entry fields with their own variable names.

If we use list we can put all the dictionaries into a list and all the entry fields into a list and then get all the results.

We can also use a textbox to display all results in order.

```
import tkinter as tk

acronym_dictionary_list = [{"A": "Annual", "AC": "Air Conditioning"},
                           {"BA": "British Airway", "BB": "BumbleBee"},
                           {"CA": "Calcium", "CO": "Company"}]
entry_list = []


def return_entry(event):
    result_box.delete(1.0, "end")
    for ndex, ent in enumerate(entry_list):
        if ent.get().strip() != "":
            sub_dict = acronym_dictionary_list[ndex]
            result_box.insert("end", "{}\n".format(sub_dict.get(ent.get().strip().upper(), "Not found")))


def entry_del():
    result_box.delete(1.0, "end")


master = tk.Tk()
master.title("The Acronym Search Engine")
master.geometry('400x200')

for i in range(3):
    tk.Label(master, text="{}:".format(chr(ord('@')+i+1)), anchor="e").grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="ew")
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(master))
    entry_list[i].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky="w")
    entry_list[i].bind('<Return>', return_entry)

result_box = tk.Text(master, width=40, height=3)
tk.Label(master, text="Result:").grid(row=3, column=0)
result_box.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

tk.Button(master, text="Clear", command=entry_del).grid(row=7, sticky="w")

master.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much. That is exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for taking your time to do that, it is much appreciated. Emily

Comment: @Emily glad to help. If my answer solved you problem please select the check mark next to my answer to mark your question as resolved :).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's because you're overwriting entry on each new "Entry"

`entry=Entry(master)`

Creates a new entry each time. This *probably* causes the behavior you're seeing where

> each time I add a new dictionary I lose the function of the previous

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have just tried the code after removing the 'master' following entry=Entry() and I still can't get it to work ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you edit the code above

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that you are replacing the old value of `entry` with a fresh one.

Comment: Do you know how I could edit the code so that I wasn't overwriting the entry value? (I have changed the code above to show where I removed 'master' to try to prevent it overwriting)